# Sending data with ajax from a link? (Without using ExtJS, jQuery or similar libraries)

Tags: javascript, ajax, hyperlink, xmlhttprequest

I have `<a href="">follow me</a>` and I want to send very simple post data to the page without reloading the page.

Edit: Oh, `onlclick` will solve my problem. I've got it.
Edit2: I mean, like `<a href="" onclick="alert('jjj');">follow me</a>`

Comment: @bruce182, yes, I'm not going to use it.

Comment: @ilhan why you won't use jQuery (or another tool that can easily help creating ajax-requests)? It's a lot easier and more crossbrowser-compatible than creating your own ajax-request.

Comment: @ilhan - so what you going to use, plain vanilla javascript....? Why reinvent the wheel?  Set aside some time to get familiar with the jQuery library - it is worth it in the long term.

Comment: @Snicksie, I want full control over my application. jQuery will load unnecessary stuff, I want it to be simple. I don't care about the old browsers. I want to learn it from scratch.

Comment: @bruce182, it will fire only a "follow" text, I don't need complicated things.

Comment: I can do it with ExtJS but I don't want to load megabytes of unnecessary thing to internet users with limited connection and paid for every bite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

There are plenty of examples online similar to what you want to achieve.

I could write the code for you, but you will gain so much from trying it yourself (and your question was vague about what serverside language your using).

If you get stuck - edit your question with the code and we will be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Ajax to post data without loading page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use jQuery and ajax, you might want to use an invisible iframe to send the data to. I recommend jQuery ajax though...